# SharePoint 2013 List View items permission

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, filter

There is one SP list (on SP 2013 Foundation) for all users to create their entries (items). Users have their individual departments columns, updated from users' profile details using workflow.

I want to create a list view with filter for all SP List Admins, in which the Admins will be able to view the items created by the users of his department.

The logged in users profile has a field department and I want to match it with the department column of each item in the list.

This will help all Admins to use the common listview but the items will be different based on their departments.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways you can try.

1. Using **Current User Filter** and list web part connection to match current user's department with the list column (department)

   **Source**: [Use Current User Filter to display items based on User’s Department](https://techenthusiast.in/2018/05/29/use-current-user-filter-to-display-items-based-on-users-department/)
2. By changing the filter query of list view using SharePoint designer.

   **Source**: [How to filter SharePoint List based on user permission](http://www.sharepointlogics.com/2014/02/how-to-filter-sharepoint-list-based-on.html)